# copy dataframe column name to a new row

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am reading a file and converting to a data frame. As the file is not organised I have kept the header as 0 while reading as csv. By default, if header = 0 pandas automatically assign the first row of df

```
   "Name"=>"Mark"  "Phone"=>"1234567"  "Id"=>"E1234"    "Admin"=>false
0  "Name"=>"Anto"  "Phone"=>"7654321"   "Dept"=>"HR"   "Id"=>"E4321"   "case"=>nil
```

My ultimate goal is to convert the dataframe into readable format as

```
Name   Phone    Id   Dept   Admin  case 
Mark   1234567  E1234        false
Anto   7654321  E4321   HR           nil
```

As the first row is already moved to column I am unable to do and manipulations on the first row. Is it possible to copy the column name and paste it as the first row of the same data frame?

NOTE: As the file is not organised the data differs in each row. Due to this I have avoided using header = NONE.

Comment: How looks original file, first 2 rows?

Comment: yes, if we look closely the second row only has index as 0. It has two rows.. After converting to dataframe only one row is seen

Answer (score 0):

One idea is create list of dictionaries and pass to `DataFrame` constructor:

```
out = []
with open("Sample.csv") as f:
    for line in f:
        d = dict([[y.strip('"') for y in x.split('=>')] for x in line.strip().split(',')])
        out.append(d)

df = pd.DataFrame(out)
print (df)
   Name    Phone     Id  Admin Dept case
0  Mark  1234567  E1234  false  NaN  NaN
1  Anto  7654321  E4321    NaN   HR  nil
```

File:

```
"Name"=>"Mark","Phone"=>"1234567","Id"=>"E1234","Admin"=>false
"Name"=>"Anto","Phone"=>"7654321","Dept"=>"HR","Id"=>"E4321","case"=>nil
```

Comment: I am sorry I misunderstood your question. The original file is in zipped format, I am getting error like 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x8b in position 1: invalid start byte. I converted the file as csv and followed your idea and I am getting TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not DataFrame

Comment: @JackJack - Hmm, so there is problem read file with `utf-8` ?

Comment: Yes, I tried extracting the file as CSV and passed that file on your idea. I am getting "TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not DataFrame"